# "Cannot read property 'xxx' of undefined" error has been occurred

Tags: javascript, typescript

I implemented following code in TypeScript.

```
class Task {
    text: string
    userId: string

    constructor(text: string, userId: string) {
        this.text = text;
        this.userId = userId;
    }
}

class TmpTask {
    userId: string;
    tasks: Task[];

    constructor(userId: string) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.tasks = [];
    }
}

const tasks: Task[] = [];
tasks.push(new Task('Send a mail now!!', 'bob'));
const tmpTasks: TmpTask[] = [];


for (let task of tasks) {
    console.log("task: ", task);

    const index = tmpTasks.findIndex( (_tmpTask, _index, _tmpTasks) => {
        return _tmpTask.userId === task.userId;
    });
    tmpTasks[index].tasks.push(task);
}
console.log("tmpTasks: ", tmpTasks);
```

When this code runs, it results in following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tasks' of undefined
    at _loop_1 (<anonymous>:23:21)
    at <anonymous>:27:5
    at HTMLButtonElement.excuteButton.onclick (http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/playground.js:247)
```

I don't understand how to fix it.

Could you give me any advices ?

Comment: `tmpTasks` is empty.

Comment: ```findIndex``` may return ```-1``` if no item matches

Comment: you could do `tmpTasks.length && tmpTasks.findIndex...`

Comment: Thank you. I added the IF condition to check the tmpTasks and it works.